# Spreadsheet to calculate weekly increase

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet with my weekly cardio and weight training average times and a total of time spent during an average visit.

I would like the final column to display the in/decrease as a percentage since the last week. Then, build a line graph that displays the upward trend.

Please know, I'm no math/spreadsheet genius. [This is it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgQ-8Qa4wxXNdHNBLS1MckFvdXhWX21SUy14WnQ0b2c&usp=sharing) so far. I read some of the docs but just got lost in them.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of "This time"  / "Last time" expressed as a percentage (by the formatting) is essentially correct, except it isn't working out the increase.

So if it was 10 minutes yesterday, and 10 minutes today, that means you did 100% of the time you did yesterday.  This is what you are calculating now.

So `(Today / Yesterday) - 1` will give you the increase (when expressed as a percentage).  The subtracting 1 removes the original amount.

For example, if it was 10 minutes yesterday, and 11 minutes today, then that is

```
11 / 10 = 1.1   
1.1 - 1 = .1
.1 * 100 = 10%
```

If you did 9 minutes today and ten yesterday:

```
9 / 10 = .9 - 1 = -.1 * 100 = -10%
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest replacing `=DIVIDE(D2 ; D3)` in `E3` with `=(D3-D2)/D2` and formatting ColumnE as percentage. This will give `#DIV/0!` errors in some cases because there is no meaningful percentage increase to be calculated where the base is zero.

For your chart, select your data in ColumnD (including`D1`), Insert, Chart, Charts, Line, click on the top image and Insert. Hopefully most of the rest will be automatic.